# Parallel primecoin mining

Tags: primecoin

Is it possible to run primecoind as a server and connect other primecoin miners to it, so that they all mine for the same wallet (on the server) in parallel? A kind of solo mining in parallel. I am using v0.1.2.0xpm-hp11-unk-beta